# jQuery binding inside JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Let's say I have an object structured like:

```
var obj = {
   prop1: "val",
   init: function(){
       this.bindings();
   },
   bindings: function(){
     $(".some-class").on('click', this.someFunction);
   },
   someFunction(){
     this.prop1--; // this does not refer to the right scope
     console.log(this); //logs $(".some-class")[0] object
   }
}
```

What if inside `someFunction` I want the context to be `obj` and not the `$(".some-class")[0]` object?

For now, I'm using this solution:

```
$(".some-class").on('click', $.proxy(this.someFunction, this));
```

It is working, but I was asking myself if there is a better/elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: `this.someFunction.bind(this)` [MDN bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: jQuery overrides this so you could use something like jQuery.proxy() or just do some clever var self=this and use self instead of this

Comment: something like `var self = this` does not change the scope in which the `function` will be executed

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    prop1: "val",
    init: function(){
        this.bindings();
    },
    bindings: function(){
        var self = this;
        $(".some-class").on('click', function(){
            self.someFunction();
        });
    },
    someFunction: function(){
        this.prop1--; // this does not refer to the right scope
        console.log(this); //logs $(".some-class")[0] object
    }
};
```